# Solving equation set with boolean operators and very specific format

Tags: systems-of-equations, boolean-algebra

I have to write a program to solve a set of equations like the following (`+` is `XOR` and `*` is `AND`):

```
b0 = 0 + (a0 * a2)
b1 = 0 + (a0 * a3) + (a1 * a2)
b2 = 0 + (a1 * a3)
b3 = 0
```

or

```
b0 = 0 + (a0 * a4)
b1 = 0 + (a0 * a5) + (a1 * a4)
b2 = 0 + (a0 * a6) + (a1 * a5) + (a2 * a4)
b3 = 0 + (a0 * a7) + (a1 * a6) + (a2 * a5) + (a3 * a4)
b4 = 0 + (a1 * a7) + (a2 * a6) + (a3 * a5)
b5 = 0 + (a2 * a7) + (a3 * a6)
b6 = 0 + (a3 * a7)
b7 = 0
```

each variable `b[0-N]` and `a[0-N]` is a single bit. I know the values of all the `b` variables, and need to find all the possible combinations of the `a` variables (it is guaranteed to not be more then a few)

The example above is a reduced set. In practice the number of variables changes, but the construction of the equations follows the same pattern.

The pattern is:

```
for i from 0 to N/2:
  for j from 0 to N/2:
    b[i+j] += a[i]*a[j+N/2]
```

If someone can give me an idea how to solve automatically even just for a specific case (say for `N=3` above), I could probably extrapolate on my own.

Comment: In the special case of $3$ I could  (personally/manually) examine all the 8 possibilities. If you have a program the can do that in general?! Millions and millions of cases could be examined but not more :)

Comment: @zoli Not more? In one of my cases, N=511. That is 2^512, way more than "millions and millions". Also, for N=3, there are 16, not 8, possibilities.

Comment: For three bits bits there are 000,...,111 eight possibilities. O am I wrong?

Comment: @zoli No, you are right, except that I defined (albeit unconventionally) in my question that the variables are `b[0-N]`, so for `N=3` we have `b0`, `b1`, `b2` and `b3`

Comment: @zoli Also, I just realized I misread your first comment. I thought you were stating that there can not be more than a few million possibilities, and so I can brute force. I see now that you were saying that I can brute force as long as there are not more than a few million possibilities.

Comment: Agreed. And sorry for misinterpreting your definitions.
Now, let ask a question: Do you think that there has to be a better method than brute forcing?